# Autodetect typeparameters of Base class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, template-argument-deduction

I have had the following code which worked fine:

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
    virtual void call(T) = 0;
};

class Derived : public Base<int> {
    void call(int);
}

template<typename T>
void registerBase(const Base<T>& ref) {}
```

This approach can autodetect the type `T` as `int` when called as `registerBase(Derived())`. The problem comes when I switch to `shared_ptr`:

```
template<typename T, typename Q>
void registerBase(shared_ptr<Q> ptr) {
    static_assert(is_base_of<Base<T>, Q>::value, "Have to supply a type extending Base<...>");
}
```

I can protect from illegal type but I can't seem to autodetect the type `T`. Is there some trick I can use to automatically down-cast the shared_ptr to `Base<T>` so template-deduction works? Or is there another way to find the typename `T`?

PS: In case `Q` extends multiply `Base<T>` I want to error (autodeduction should fail).

Comment: `template<class T> T helper(const Base<T> &); template<class Q> using base_param = decltype(helper(std::declval<Q>()));`

Comment: @T.C. I believe that is the correct answer. Please post as an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: `register` is a keyword

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, I fixed that

Comment: I wish it *wasn't* a keyword, because I've tried to use it exactly like that several times and gone "doh!" when it won't compile :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably a gazillion ways to do this. Here's one:

```
template<class T>
T helper(const Base<T> &); // not defined

template<class Q> 
using base_param = decltype(helper(std::declval<Q>()));
```

In actual code, you'd probably want to put `helper` in a `details` namespace (and probably also change the names).

This will break if you have an odd case of `T` being a type that can't be returned - e.g., an array type. It's easily fixable by altering `helper`'s return type to, e.g., `identity<T>` and then also altering the definition of `base_param` accordingly.